# Replacing backlash (\) in a list

Tags: python, string, special-characters, python-3.8

I need to replace all backlashs in this list:

```
lista = ['06\\/01\\/2021', '04\\/01\\/2021', '30\\/12\\/2020', '29\\/12\\/2020', '28\\/12\\/2020']
```

I've tried to achieve it using the following code:

```
lista = [list.replace('\\', '') for l in lista]
```

And many other ways however the main issue is that Python wont accept \ as a string as it is a special character.

How do I work around that? How can I convert it into a string? I am currently using pycharm on Python 3.8.5

Comment: don't use `list` as name, it's built-in function. you want `spam = [item.replace('\\', '') for ltem in spam]` where `spam` is the original list.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the special characters (surprisingly enough). You used `list.replace` where you needed `l.replace`. (Also, these are really bad choices of variable names, and you're hiding the `list` builtin.)

Comment: it seems that you are using `list` instead of `l`:

```
list = [l.replace('\\', '') for l in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate of [Removing backslashes from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160752/removing-backslashes-from-a-string-in-python).

In either case, `[l.replace("\\", "") for l in your_list]` should work.

Comment: Wow. same idea, at same time.

Comment: it's not duplicate, because OP problem is they apply `replace()` on the list, not on the list element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you:

```py
lst = `your orig. list`    # don't use Python built-in `list`. it will conflict...
ll = [l.replace('\\', '') for l in lst]
>>> ll
['06/01/2021', '04/01/2021']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['06\\/01\\/2021', '04\\/01\\/2021', '30\\/12\\/2020', '29\\/12\\/2020', '28\\/12\\/2020']
list = [l.replace('\\', '') for l in list]
```

have an error your code, note the **l**.replace(...) instead **list**.replace(...)